# Trying to update a DataRow in C# with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I'm trying to find, then update, a specific DataRow in a DataTable. I've tried a few things based on my searches, and the code below seems to be the closest I can get. The linq will return one row. With that row, I'd like to update column values (Status, StopTime, Duration). I can't for the life of me find how to do this.. I've tried casting, but I'm new to linq and don't see how to update these values.

```
private DataTable downloadProcStatusTable;

void UpdateDataDownloadProcedureList(ProcedureStats ProcStats)          
{
      var currentStatRow = from currentStat in downloadProcStatusTable.AsEnumerable()
                           where currentStat.Field<String>("ProcedureName") == ProcStats.ProcName
                           select currentStat;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query as it stands actually gives you an `IEnumerable<DataRow>`.  You need to do this to get the actual row:

```
  var currentStatRow = (from currentStat in downloadProcStatusTable.AsEnumerable()
                       where currentStat.Field<String>("ProcedureName") == ProcStats.ProcName 
                       select currentStat).SingleOrDefault();
```

You should then be able to use the `currentStatRow`  variable to modify the column values.

Answer (score 1):

## Outline

1. Load the existing entity from the database (unless you have one that you can re-attach, in which case you could avoid this additional query)
2. Update the properties as needed
3. Submit the changes back to the database using `SubmitChanges()`

## Implementation

I wasn't exactly sure where your variables are and the names, but this should give you a good start...

```
void UpdateDataDownloadProcedureList(ProcedureStats ProcStats)          
    {
          var currentStatRow = (from currentStat in downloadProcStatusTable.AsEnumerable()
                               where currentStat.Field<String>("ProcedureName") == ProcStats.ProcName
                               select currentStat).FirstOrDefault();

         currentStatRow.Status = ProcStats.Status;
         currentStatRow.StopTime = ProcStats.StopTime;
         currentStatRow.Duration = ProcStats.Duration;

         downloadProcStatusTable.SubmitChanges();
    }
```